# How to remove duplicates based on a condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a SQL Query to select all the records.

If a GROUP+SEMIGROUP combination is found as a duplicate, I want to pick up the one where "TOTAL" column is filled, and eliminate the other.

Sample input and output:
[image]

Comment: please add your code. if I understood you should use ```dustinct``` after ```SELECT```

Answer (score -1):

i share two solution.

1. the first solution used group by.

```
create table t (
group_ int,
semi_group VARCHAR(30),
total int,
semi_total int
);

INSERT INTO 
    t(group_, semi_group, total, semi_total)
VALUES
    (10,'A',56, null),
    (10,'A',null, 34),
    (11,'G',34, null),
    (12,'H',23, null),
    (13,'J',12, null),
    (13,'J',null, 55);
    
    
    select 
    group_, 
    semi_group, 
    sum(total) total, sum(semi_total)
    from t
    group by group_, semi_group;
```

2. use condition, for example if you want total is null and semitotal is not null use semitotal value and if inverse use total.

```
   select 
    group_, 
    semi_group, 
    case when sum(total) is null and  sum(semi_total) is null then
            0
        when sum(total) is null and  sum(semi_total) is not null then
            sum(semi_total)
        else    
        sum(total)
    end total
    from t
    group by group_, semi_group;
```

the result is this.

| group_ | semi_group | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | A | 56 |
| 11 | G | 34 |
| 12 | H | 23 |
| 13 | J | 12 |